# CKEditor 5 paste as plain text

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is there an option to paste always from the clipboard as plain text?

I tried it that way, but that does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#text'), {
        toolbar: [
            'heading',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'blockQuote',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    }).then(function (editor) {

        this.listenTo(editor.editing.view, 'clipboardInput', function (event, data) {
            // No log.
            console.log('hello');
        });

    }).catch(function (error) {

    });

});
```

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_clipboard_clipboard-Clipboard.html

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/clipboard.html

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:paste

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`clipboardInput`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:clipboardInput) event is fired on the [`Document`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html), not the [`View`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_view-View.html). So the first thing will be to listen on the right object.

The second thing is ensuring that the content inserted into the editor is a plain text. This can be done in two ways:

- HTML taken from the clipboard can be "plain-textified". But this is hard.
- We can take plain-text from the clipboard and insert that into the editor. However, the editor expects HTML to be pasted, so you need to "HTMLize" this plain-text. CKEditor 5 offers a function for that – [`plainTextToHtml()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_clipboard_utils_plaintexttohtml.html#static-function-plainTextToHtml).

To override the editor's default behaviour we'll need to override this callback: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/blob/a7819b9e6e2bfd64cc27f65d8e56b0d26423d156/src/clipboard.js#L137-L158

To do that, we'll listen to the same event (with a higher priority), do all the same things, but ignore `text/html` flavour of the clipboard data. Finally, we 'll call `evt.stop()` to block the default listener from being executed and ruining our job:

```
import plainTextToHtml from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/utils/plaintexttohtml';

// ...

const clipboardPlugin = editor.plugins.get( 'Clipboard' );
const editingView = editor.editing.view;

editingView.document.on( 'clipboardInput', ( evt, data ) => {
    if ( editor.isReadOnly ) {
        return;
    }

    const dataTransfer = data.dataTransfer;

    let content = plainTextToHtml( dataTransfer.getData( 'text/plain' ) );

    content = clipboardPlugin._htmlDataProcessor.toView( content );

    clipboardPlugin.fire( 'inputTransformation', { content, dataTransfer } );

    editingView.scrollToTheSelection();

    evt.stop();
} );
```

EDIT:

Starting from CKEditor 27.0.0 the code has changed (you can read more about it here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migration/migration-to-27.html#clipboard-input-pipeline-integration)

```
import plainTextToHtml from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/utils/plaintexttohtml';
//...
const clipboardPlugin = editor.plugins.get( 'ClipboardPipeline' );
const editingView = editor.editing.view;

editingView.document.on( 'clipboardInput', ( evt, data ) => {
    if ( editor.isReadOnly ) {
        return;
    }
    const dataTransfer = data.dataTransfer;
    let content = plainTextToHtml( dataTransfer.getData( 'text/plain' ) );
    data.content = editor.data.htmlProcessor.toView( content );
                
    editingView.scrollToTheSelection();
}, { priority: 'high' } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Without any imports:

```
.then(editor => {
                editor.editing.view.document.on('clipboardInput', (evt, data) => {
                    data.content = editor.data.htmlProcessor.toView(data.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
                });
            })
```

You have complete methods in [documentation of ckeditor clipboard events](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_clipboard_clipboardobserver-ClipboardObserver.html)